# Will drywall mud stick to shellac-based primer?

Tags: drywall, primer

We are preparing to prime interior walls using a shellac-based primer, followed with a setting compound mud.  Will the mud stick adequately to the shellac-based product or do we need to use another type of primer over the shellac primer?

Comment: Why would you prime prior to mudding?

Comment: Because there was a long history of smoking in this house and we want to permanently 'bury' any odor.  Our understanding is that shellac primer is the only one that will achieve this goal.

Comment: So is this existing sheetrock? If so, what are you mudding on the exiting sheetrock?

Comment: The walls are currently painted, and have lath and plaster.  Our end goal is to 'bury' any odors with the shellac, then mud (skim-coat) over the walls to create a different texture to the walls.

Comment: If the walls are already painted, that's an issue right there. You'd likely going to have to go with a quality primer first. Something that will allow the mud to nicely bond--but even then, you're somewhat at the mercy of the existing layers of paint bonding well. So, prime, skim coat, THEN shellac. (Actually, if you go with a really good primer, you might not even need the shellac).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. This fine plastering expert actually [recommends it](http://www.bristegroup.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=45&Itemid=82):

> If the surface is new, eliminate any possibility of coating failure by priming the surface in an oil primer, B-I-N SHELLAC BASE is preferred.

Here is another [expert plasterer](http://www.fauxforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=6915) doing the same.

Comment: I am attempting an identical project (nicotine stained walls and shellac). My email is on my profile if you would like to discuss your experience.

Comment: My experience is that priming before you mud makes the mudding job much better.  The mud will dry more evenly.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve done a lot of small projects doing this exact thing but never whole walls. However, I would do at least two coats of primer (natural Shellac is best) and then sand (220 grit) and wipe the walls down with a damp (not soaking wet) cloth and then allow to dry well before plastering. *You may need to rinse / wring the cloth a few times depending on how much dust you’re picking up.